# Python I'm trying to make a program that writes data to a file then reads that data

Tags: file, python-3.x

```
def meanRating(afile):
    rating = 0
    divider = 0
    for line in afile:
        listline = line.split(',')
        print(listline)
        rating = rating + int(listline[2])
        divider = divider + 1
    print(rating/divider)

def main():
    file2 = open('blank.txt','w')
    data = 0 # Just assigning data before the loop
    while data != '\n':
        data = input('Enter your data followed by a comma using the Netflix movie rating format. Enter a blank line when you are done.')
        data = data.split(',')
        if len(data) != 4:
            print('That data is incorrect')
        else:
            data = ''.join(data)
            file2.write(data)
            file2.write('\n')
    file2.close()
    file2 = open('blank.txt','r')
    print('cal')
    print('This is the average rating of your movie:',meanRating(file2))
    file2.close()
main()
```

The problem here is that after it creates and writes to the file it does not perform the meanRating function. Edit:Just posting the current version.

Comment: removed. still not performing the meanRating function

Comment: I also removed the return 'That data is incorrect...' that was a silly error it prints that now.

Comment: Try printing any string before the print containing the function call. Also why are you closing the file only once? Close it before opening it again.

Comment: did that it's not printing that string not sure what's stopping it! perhaps my while loop is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues with your code:

- If you want to allow your user to end the imput when a blank line is inserted check that before trying anything otherwise you'll just get "'That data is incorrect' " over and over again e.g `if data.strip() == "": break`
- `data = ''.join(data)` should be `data = ','.join(data)` as later you expect it to be comma separated.
- The function `meanRating` should `return rating/divider` instead of just printing it.